# Robot Framework: Read Log In Credendials From a File

Tags: robotframework, testcase

I am new to Robot Framework and I was wondering if there is a way to not only hide login credentials in a generated log by using `--removekeywords`, but also read password and username from a separate file. Does anyone know a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to read variables from files (password and username in your case) you can either declare a [variable file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files) in your test case or specifiy it with a command line parameter.

Your file might look as simple as this:

```
USERNAME = "user"
PASSWORD = "pass"
```

Given it is called myvariables.py you can declare it in the settings of your test case:

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    myvariables.py
```

or use the command line parameter `--variablefile myvariables.py`

Yet another way is to use the [built-in keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Import%20Variables) `Import Variables`. Variables imported with this keyword are set into the test suite scope.